# What's the difference between a Laplace functional and a Laplace transform?

Tags: definition, laplace-transform

I'm reading a book on stochastic processes at the moment, and I have come across the following definitions.

- The Laplace transform of a function $X(t)$ is $E[\exp(-\lambda X(t))]$.
- The Laplace functional of the point process $N$ is the non-negative function given by $\Psi_N(f) = E[\exp(-N(f))]$.

These definitions look practically the same to me (are they basically just moment generating functions), could someone please explain the difference?

Comment: The difference is the name. They are the same thing, just defined on different spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A Laplace *transform* is often used to simplify differential equations that would be normally be complex (e.g. step/Heaviside functions, unit impulses) into simple algebra, and then transform back to the original.

A Laplace *functional* may be the probability analog to the Laplace transform, but as I'm not familiar with probability, that's my best estimate.

You are correct they are generating functions, however.